# loading elements from file into a tree in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, tree

I am trying to make a tree from the info in a text document. For example in example.txt we have aritmetchic expression `(3 + x) * (5 - 2)`. I want to make a tree which seems like this:

```
Node * (Node + (Leaf 3) (Leaf x)) (Node - (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)
```

So far after a lot of unsuccessful attempts I have done this:

```
data Tree a = Empty                             
            | Leaf a
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)  
    deriving (Show)
```

this is the tree I use and :

```
take name = do
       elements <- readFile name
       return elements
```

So how can I put the elements in the tree?

Comment: First piece of advice; skip the file reading until you can turn a String into a tree. If you have `readTree :: String -> Tree X` you can then do `take name = readFile name >>= return.readTree`

Comment: There's a nice [text parsing tutorial in School of Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/attoparsec)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a data type to put in the tree that can store both operations and values.  One way to do this would be to create an ADT representing everything you want to store in the tree:

```
data Eval a
    = Val a
    | Var Char
    | Op (a -> a -> a)

type EvalTree a = Tree (Eval a)
```

But this isn't really ideal because someone could have `Leaf (Op (+))`, which doesn't make much sense here.  Rather, I would suggest structuring it as

```
data Eval a
    = Val a
    | Var Char
    | Op (a -> a -> a) (Eval a) (Eval a)
```

Which is essentially the tree structure you have, just restricted to be syntactically correct.  Then you can write a simple evaluator as

```
eval :: Eval a -> Data.Map.Map Char a -> Maybe a
eval vars (Val a) = Just a
eval vars (Var x) = Data.Map.lookup x vars
eval vars (Op op l r) = do
    left <- eval l
    right <- eval r
    return $ left `op` right
```

This will just walk down both branches, evaluating as it goes, then finally returning the computed value.  You just have to supply it with a map of variables to values to use

So for example, `(3 + x) * (5 - 2)` would be represented as `Op (*) (Op (+) (Val 3) (Var 'x')) (Op (-) (Val 5) (Val 2))`.  All that's left is to parse the file, which is another problem entirely.

Comment: @user3050163 You want to be able to parse a file and turn it into that structure, yes?  What parsing methods have you tried?

Comment: yes,this is what i want ,but i have no idea,absolutely no idea.
i am new in haskell and i am trying to learn from some books,but it will be easier if i see something which is really working and examine it.

Comment: @user3050163 Give me a few minutes and I'll try to put together a simple parsing example.

Comment: @user3050163 Instead of giving you an example of this, I will instead direct you towards [this](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/9_Evaluator) tutorial at FPComplete that walks you through exactly what you want to do in a lot more depth than I am willing to give in a stackoverflow response.  It probably is better written than I would give anyway.